# Choose highest value in various rows and merge

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

what I am looking to do is merge several rows of data to be displayed as a single row. Based on the highest value of a row. So only keep the records with the highest values

FROM THIS:

| ContractID | Months |
| --- | --- |
| 140 | 12.8 |
| 140 | 12.9 |
| 140 | **13.0** |
| 130 | 8.1 |
| 130 | **8.2** |
| 126 | **1.5** |

TO THIS:

| ContractID | Months |
| --- | --- |
| 140 | 13.0 |
| 130 | 8.2 |
| 126 | 1.5 |

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: GROUP BY, MAX().

Comment: Read up on mysql aggregate functions here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

that would be group by and get the max in each group:

```
select ContractID , max(Months)
from yourtable
group by ContractID
```